# How to Stop loop inside while

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
  public void ChangeDailyTasks()
  {
        gameManager.ActiveTasks.today = gameManager.DateTimeNow();
        gameManager.ActiveTasks.Dailytasks = new List<Task>();
        while (gameManager.ActiveTasks.Dailytasks.Count != 5)
        {
            var addingTask = gameManager.TaskList[UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 
            gameManager.TaskList.Count)];
            foreach (Task i in gameManager.ActiveTasks.Dailytasks)
                if (i.name != addingTask.name)
                    gameManager.ActiveTasks.Dailytasks.Add(addingTask);
        }
}
```

If I call This function my computer is freezing What i doing is not correctly I just wanna Add 5 new Elements  Inside  List gameManager.ActiveTasks.Dailytasks. Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Issue(s)

- in general rather use `<= 5` ... With your current `!= 5` if for what reason ever your list has `6` or more elements → **endless loop!**
- as I see it you are trying to iterate over and add elements to the **same** collection!

  - First of all this would cause an **exception** anyway since it is not allowed to modify a collection at the same time while you are iterating it.
  - Secondly **it is empty**! → The code within `foreach` is **never executed** → nothing is ever being added to your list → **endless loop!**

  I think what you wanted to do would have been something like

  ```
   var alreadyAdded = false;
   foreach (Task i in gameManager.ActiveTasks.Dailytasks)
   {
       if (i == addingTask)
       {
           alreadyAdded = true;
           continue;
       }
   }

   if(!alreadyAdded)
   {
       gameManager.ActiveTasks.Dailytasks.Add(addingTask);
   }
  ```

  which can be done way easier using

  ```
   if(!gameManager.ActiveTasks.Dailytasks.Contains(addingTask)) 
   {
       gameManager.ActiveTasks.Dailytasks.Add(addingTask);
   }
  ```
- Even if it would work that way (or after the before mentioned code) what if there are not enough Tasks available to get 5 unique ones? → Again **endless loop**.

---

#### Solution

It looks like what you are trying to achieve is having a list with `5` **random** but **unique** elements picked from the available ones in `gameManager.TaskList`.

So instead of a `while` loop you probably rather want to do

- randomize the list of available tasks
- pick 5 of them sequentially

You can do this in a single line using

- [Linq `OrderBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby) with [`Random.value`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random-value.html) as order critera
- followed by [Linq `Take`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.take) to pick the first `5` items from the already randomized enumeration → as they are already randomized you can now go sequential

=> You get 5 random unique Tasks (or if not enough are available you get only as many as exist - can be 0).

Something like

```
using System.Linq;

...

public void ChangeDailyTasks()
{
    gameManager.ActiveTasks.today = gameManager.DateTimeNow();
    gameManager.ActiveTasks.Dailytasks = gameManager.TaskList.OrderBy(t => Random.value).Take(5).ToList();
}
```